# Is $f$ integrable over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

Tags: integration, analysis

I was asked to determine the integrability of

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } \ (x,y)=(\frac{p}{2^n},\frac{q}{2^n}), 0<p,q<2^n\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and to find $\int_Ef$ if it exists where $E=[0,1]\times[0,1]$

I have almost no idea how to solve this one.
I was thinking that maybe since $\frac{p}{2^n}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, every point where $f=1$ is not continuous since and this is also true for those points where $f=0$? In that way maybe we can say that $f$ at every point not continuous so it is not integrable.
(Also I was learning Lebesgue's Theorem and was wondering whether that helps.)

Comment: What is the value of $f$ for the first branch?

Comment: Isn't $f$ just the zero function?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a typo. Now it's fixed and I also edited the question. Also I added some of my thoughts on how to solve this one.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed for $f$?

Comment: I don't think so. My understanding is that $f=1$ if there  are some integers $p,q$ and $n$ such that $(x,y)=(\frac{p}{2^n},\frac{q}{2^n})$

Answer (score 1):

First: You didn't mention a measure you are using so let's assume you are using the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $E=[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

If we additionally assume $0 < p,q < 2^n$ to be integers (as mentioned in the comments) then all points of the form $\left(\frac{p}{2^n},\frac{q}{2^n}\right) \in E$ are countable.
Hence the set where $f = 1$ holds is a countable union of nullsets, hence a nullset.

So $f \equiv 0$ except on a nullset and it follows $$\int_E f d\lambda = 0$$

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with the concept of Lebesque measure. I think the question was asking if $f$ is Riemann integrable. Also, could you elaborate the reason that the set E is countable? Thanks.

Comment: Then you should have been more detailed in your initial question!
But nevertheless: The Riemann integral exists as well due to the Lebesgue-Vitali theorem. $f$ is continuous up to a set of measure zero hence Riemann integrable. 

I didn't mention that $E = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ is countable but the set where $f = 1$ holds!
And this is countable because all integers are countable.